# Why did I get Error Cannot Get/ Node.js (in browser)

Tags: node.js

This is what I have, the filename "pages" actually exists 
The code is:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function () { console.log('Listening to port 3000') });

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('pages'));
app.post('/storeData', storeData);


function storeData(req, res) {
   var input = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
   var to_save = input.email + ',' + input.password + '\n';
   fs.appendFile('./loginDetails.txt', to_save, (err) => {
       if (err) console.log('Error occured while storing data!');
       res.send('Data stored successfully');
   });
}
```

The Error (in browser):

```
Cannot GET /
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined a `get` route for `/`. If you try to access a file under `pages` instead of just the root service, it should work.

Comment: Could you write the correct code for me